# Trying my own string method to remove vowels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this function to remove lowercase vowels from a string. This function is not working for some strings. If the string has more than one occurrence of the same vowel only one vowel is being removed. [Edit: sorry I forgo to include 'y' as a vowel in my example below.] Thank you for your help.

```
var string = "heelloo world";
var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

String.prototype.character = function name() {
    var i;
    for ( i = 0; i < vowel.length; i++) {
        var secondLoop = string.length;
        for ( j = 0; j < secondLoop; j++) {
            if (vowel[i] == string.charAt(j)) {
                string = string.slice(0, j).concat(string.slice(j + 1, secondLoop));
            }

        }
    }
}

string.character();
console.log(string);
//hello wrld
```

Comment: [what's the question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This code is not working properly. Eg if i pass "heelloo world" to var string and results is "hello wrld". Still final output has vowels.

Comment: @Joeytje50: reading the post suffices to figure out what the problem is. "and it is not working for some strings".

Comment: Woah, looks like someone's trying to build a nuclear power plant to light a bulb...

Comment: What about when y is a vowel and u is not?

Answer (score 3):

When you remove a character from the string, you're skipping the next character in the loop because the string is now one character shorter but the pointer (`j`) still points at the same position. You need to decrement the counter when you remove a character.

```js
var string = "heelloo world";
var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

String.prototype.character = function name() {
    var i;
    for ( i = 0; i < vowel.length; i++) {
        var secondLoop = string.length;
        for ( j = 0; j < secondLoop; j++) {
            if (vowel[i] == string.charAt(j)) {
                string = string.slice(0, j).concat(string.slice(j + 1, secondLoop));
                j--;           // take the removed character into account
                secondLoop--;  // string is now one character shorter
            }

        }
    }
}

string.character();
console.log(string);
```

That said, it would be much easier to implement the same thing using a regex, unless you have a compelling reason to avoid it.

```js
var string = "heelloo world";

string = string.replace( /[aeiou]/g, '' );

console.log(string);  // hll wrld
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code, during the second, nested loop, when the loop increments on the next iteration it has passed the second instance of a vowel, i.e. The loop is at 2 but the second vowel is at 1. Try subtracting 1 from the loop control variable secondLoop when ever the if condition that concat's the split strings fires?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve is to simply use a regex replace to do this:

```js
String.prototype.character = function() {
  return this.replace(/[aeiou]+/g, ''); //replace a, e, i, o and u with nothing.
}

function submit() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = input.character();
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="eeexaammpleeee">
<div id="output"></div>
<button onclick="submit()">Go!</button>
```

Comment: Yes.... but trying with own menthod... thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a good old regex
    var string = "heelloo world";
    var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

```
String.prototype.character = function() {
    return this.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '');
}

console.log(string.character());
```

Comment: [ninja'd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27213960/1256925).

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
    var string = "heelloo world";
    var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    var new_string = "";
    var safe = "";

    for (x = 0; x < string.length; x++)
    {
        var removeChar = false;
        for (y = 0; y < vowel.length; y++)
        {
            if (string[x] == vowel[y] && safe != vowel[y])
            {
                if (string[x+1] == vowel[y])
                {
                    safe = vowel[y];
                    removeChar = true;
                }
                else
                safe = "";

                break;
            }
        }
        if (!removeChar)
        {
            new_string += string[x];

            var isVowel = false;
            for (y = 0; y < vowel.length; y++)
            {
                if (string[x] == vowel[y])
                {
                    isVowel = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isVowel)
            safe = "";
        }
    }
    alert(new_string);
```

this will yield "hello world".